# How to change the schema of stored procedure without recreating it

Tags: sql-server

I have some Stored procedure with "SalesTraining" schema.
I want to change all SalesTraining schemas to "Sales".
Is there any better way than recreating the stored procedures?
thnx

[image]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use [ALTER SCHEMA (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423.aspx) if you are on SQL Server 2005 or later.

```
ALTER SCHEMA Sales TRANSFER SalesTraining.MainSP;
```